# How can I make PS3 recognize an HDMI to VGA converted cable as a displayable screen?

Tags: ps3

I tried to hook my PS3 up to a projector using an hdmi cable converted to vga, but it doesn't seem to want to recognize it as a screen, and it keeps pulsing video but not sustaining it.  Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: Best guess is that because your projector doesn't support [HDCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection) - it can't when using a VGA signal, the PS3 decides it can't display a picture.  This affected early models as well.

Comment: @MBraedley hooray for DRM, making products worse for consumers since the dawn of computing.

Comment: Just so everything is covered, try resetting the video output by holding down the Power Button from off until you hear 2 beeps. Make sure only the video cable you want to use is connected.

Comment: Isn't the problem more likely to be that HDMI is a digital signal and VGA is analogue - meaning that without a converter they are not compatible. I am not 100% so only commenting for now.

Comment: @Colin The "HDMI to VGA converted cable" presumably includes a converter.

Comment: @RossRidge Not necessarily, many of the cables you buy on ebay just have the two connectors wired up and no actual converter.

Comment: @Colin The original poster twice described it as a "converted cable", so there's no reason to assume it's not. The "pulsing video but not sustaining it" part suggests a converter as its at least partially working.

Comment: @RossRidge you may be correct however if the OP is not familiar with the requirement for an actual unit to change the signal type he could be loosely using the term 'converter' to describe the cable itself. I think that it is definitely worth pointing out so the the OP can ascertain weather or not it could be the problem.

Comment: @Colin This question is over a year old. By now the original poster has likely either found some other solution or given up.

Comment: @RossRidge I know, I noticed that before I posted the original comment, I may add an answer later after further research. The question and the potential answer are still relevant to someone else with the same problem finding this question today.

Comment: I figured out that I could the cable that splits into one video and two audio connectors with my projector.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I have successfully done this is with a single cable that has a HDMI male as the first connection and ends in either a VGA or SVGA, You will need to reset the Video as Michael Frank suggested.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to display settings nd then set the resolution to 720p in custom settings